# findbugs in maven for single module

Tags: maven, findbugs

I want to run findbugs for a single module from my project. Updated the pom.xml like
http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html

< project>

```
  [...]
  < build>

  [...]
 < plugin>

    < groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    < artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    < version>2.5.2</version>
        < configuration>
          < findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
          < onlyAnalyze>nafw.-</onlyAnalyze>
        < /configuration>
        < executions>
        < execution>
          < phase>verify</phase>
          < goals>
            < goal>check</goal>
            < /goals>
        < /execution>
        < /executions>
  < /plugin>
[...]
```

But, still when I run "mvn findbugs:findbugs" or "mvn verify", findbugs is run for whole project and not for single module i.e. "nafw". Please help what could be the possible answer for it and where I am incorrect.

Comment: Can you include that code using code tags within your question as opposed to a comment? Use the edit button under your question.

Comment: Hi, please remove the code from your comment. Add the code snippets relevant to your question in the question itself. You can find the edit link just below the question. As it stands, this is not a good question.

Comment: @VarunVohra I have updated the question with the code

Comment: @Ren I have updated the question with code